# rails left join and include non-existing left table records

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to achieve a "real" left join via the rails AR querying interface, but can't find out how to do so, which needs to be eagerly loaded...

I'm able to generate the following query via the AR interface

```
scope :user_search, lambda {|user_id| includes(:trip_item).where("trip_items.user_id = ? OR trip_items.user_id IS NULL", user_id).order("trip_items.updated_at desc") }

apartments = Apartment.where(:location_id => near_by_locations.map(&:id).uniq)

    apartments = apartments.where.not(:id => exclude) unless exclude == nil

    apartments = apartments.where("apartments.updated_at >= :date", :date => 20.days.ago)
    apartments = apartments.where("apartments.price >= ?", search.min_price)
    apartments = apartments.where("apartments.price <= ?", search.max_price) unless search.max_price == nil
    apartments = apartments.where("apartments.rooms >= ?", search.min_rooms)
    apartments = apartments.where("apartments.rooms <= ?", search.max_rooms) unless search.max_rooms == nil


    apartments = apartments.order("apartments.updated_at DESC").user_search(user_id)

 SELECT * FROM "apartments" 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "trip_items" ON "trip_items"."apartment_id" = "apartments"."id"
 WHERE "apartments"."location_id" IN (1, 8, 11, 13, 12, 7) AND ("apartments"."id" NOT IN (27, 8)) 
 AND (apartments.updated_at >= '2014-02-03 19:02:11.609227') AND (apartments.price >= 100) 
 AND (apartments.price <= 5000) AND (apartments.rooms >= 1.0) 
 AND (trip_items.user_id = 1 OR trip_items.user_id IS NULL) 
 ORDER BY apartments.updated_at DESC, trip_items.updated_at desc
```

but i need the following, to return empty left-table records:

```
 SELECT * FROM "apartments" 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "trip_items" ON "trip_items"."apartment_id" = "apartments"."id" AND trip_items.user_id = 1
  WHERE "apartments"."location_id" IN (1, 8, 11, 13, 12, 7) AND ("apartments"."id" NOT IN (27, 8)) 
 AND (apartments.updated_at >= '2014-02-03 19:02:11.609227') AND (apartments.price >= 100) 
 AND (apartments.price <= 5000) AND (apartments.rooms >= 1.0) 
 ORDER BY apartments.updated_at DESC, trip_items.updated_at desc
```

help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

First thing, why this line appears two times ?

```
apartments = apartments.where("apartments.rooms <= ?", search.max_rooms) unless search.max_rooms == nil
```

Anyway use this

```
 apartments = Apartment.where(:location_id => near_by_locations.map(&:id).uniq) 
 apartments = apartments.where.not(:id => exclude) unless exclude == nil
 apartments = apartments.where("apartments.updated_at >= :date", :date => 20.days.ago) 
 apartments = apartments.where("apartments.price >= ?", search.min_price) 
 apartments = apartments.where("apartments.price <= ?", search.max_price) unless search.max_price == nil
 apartments = apartments.where("apartments.rooms >= ?", search.min_rooms) 
 apartments = apartments.includes(:trip_items).where("trip_items.user_id = ?", user_id)
 apartments = apartments.order("apartments.updated_at DESC ,trip_items.updated_at desc")
```

This will generate this following

```
SELECT * FROM "apartments" 
WHERE "apartments"."location_id" IN (1, 8, 11, 13, 12, 7)
AND ("apartments"."id" NOT IN (27, 8)) 
AND (apartments.updated_at >= '2014-02-03 19:02:11.609227') 
AND (apartments.price >= 100) 
AND (apartments.price <= 5000) AND (apartments.rooms >= 1.0) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "trip_items" ON "trip_items"."apartment_id" = "apartments"."id" AND trip_items.user_id = 1
ORDER BY apartments.updated_at DESC, trip_items.updated_at desc
```